# Echo a variable with $i PHP

Tags: php, variables, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a dynamic for loop with some database connection.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++): ?>

<?php echo $question[0]->option

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Where the option is in database stored like this: option1, option2, option3 etc..

I have the $i variable which does the counting, but I do not know how I put that into the $question[0]->option variable. Tried $question[0]->option,$i etc, but no luck.

Comment: Does `echo $question[0]->option{$i}` work?

Comment: Normalise your database. Move the options to another table and make the 1, 2, 3 another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $num = "option".$i;
    echo $question[0]->$num;
}
?>
```

Comment: Always surround variables like `$num` here with `{}`

Comment: This worked great!! Thank you, and I am a bit embarassed that I didnt try that solution.

Why should I sorround variables with {}?

Comment: @PLB why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @PLB this case is so insignificant, don't you think it's just the matter of preference?

Comment: @madfriend No, I don't think that it's matter of preference because while reading code of quite big application, structure like `$question[0]->$num` can be simply understood as `$question[0]->num` (we are humans and our eye can simply miss `$` symbol while reading large code). but when `$num` is surrounded with `{}` you know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to open and close the php tags in a block of only php code.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++):
    $optionname = "option$i";
    echo $question[0]->$optionname
endfor;
?>
```

Comment: Thats completely true, my code was just snipped out of a bigger code where I have some HTML between, and think it looks best to split the php tags and code. :)